# Azure yaml same key issue when checking out same repository in multiple jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have reusable build template job. In my pipeline, I'm reusing this template every time I want to build new application. Inside this build template, it has inline checkout step. Problem occurs if I checkout same repository and branch.

Template structure

```
# **pipeline.yaml**
stages:    
- template: templates/group-build.yaml
  parameters:
    branchRef: ${{ variables.branchRef}}


# -----------------------------------------
# **templates/group-build.yaml**
parameters:
  - name: branchRef
    type: string

stages:
 - stage: 'Build'
   displayName: 'Build'
   variables:           
jobs: 
  - template: template/functionapp-build-job.yaml
    parameters:
      branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}

  - template: template/webapp-build-job.yaml
    parameters:
      branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}
  

# -----------------------------------------
# **template/functionapp-build-job.yaml**
parameters:
  - name: branchRef
    type: string

jobs:
- template: templates/function/build-job.yaml
  parameters:
    repository: repo
    branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}
    project: functionapp/function.csproj'


# -----------------------------------------
# **templates/function/build-job.yaml**
parameters:
 - name: repository
   type: string

 - name: project
   type: string

 - name: componentName
   type: string

 - name: branchRef
   type: string

jobs:
  - job: JOB_${{ parameters.componentName}}_BUILD # <- Component is unique
    displayName: Build ${{ parameters.componentName}} Job
    
 steps: 
   // Checking out same repo is not allowed here
   - checkout: git://project/${{ parameters.repository }}@${{ parameters.branchRef}}
   - Other Task here...


# -----------------------------------------
# **template/webapp-build-job.yaml**
# Same structure as function app...
```

This is how it looks like structurally

```
Pipeline
  Stages:
   - Stage:
     Jobs:
       - Job: Web App Build
         Steps:
          - checkout: 'Here I call same repo and branch but different build steps'
       - Job: Function App Build
         Steps:
          - checkout: 'Here I call same repo and branch but different build steps'
```

Validation issue image

[image: validation-issue]

[image]

Adding resources in pipeline is not my option because `refs` is being stored in variable group, which is not support to resolve due to limitation of azure yaml as stated [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-use-variable-branch-for-pipeline-resourc/1117588).

Any suggestion or idea to circumvent this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you checkout the repo in group-build.yaml before you include the templates, rather than in build-job.yaml?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT, I added few details in my question and comments in your answer.

Comment: @ConradAlbrecht, I would like to preserve the current structure because this template is being reused by different pipelines across different repositories.

Comment: I confirmed that you can't check-out repository with same name. One solution is to publish the files you want to reuse accross different jobs as artifact.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample, the template webapp-build-job.yaml and functionapp-build-job.yaml are reference the same yaml：build-job.yaml.

In this case, the job names (`- job: JOB_BUILD`) are the same key and this can be the root cause of this issue.

To solve this issue, you can define job name as a parameter and assign value in webapp-build-job.yaml and functionapp-build-job.yaml.

For example:

**build-job.yaml**

```
parameters:
 - name: repository
   type: string

 - name: project
   type: string

 - name: jobname
   type: string

 - name: branchRef
   type: string

jobs:
  - job: ${{ parameters.jobname }}
    displayName: Build Job
    steps: 
    - checkout: git://Artifacts/${{ parameters.repository }}@${{ parameters.branchRef}}
```

**functionapp-build-job.yaml**

```
parameters:
  - name: branchRef
    type: string

jobs:
- template: build-job.yaml
  parameters:
    repository: Repo11
    branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}
    jobname: test1
    project: functionapp/function.csproj'
```

**webapp-build-job.yaml**

```
parameters:
  - name: branchRef
    type: string

jobs:
- template: build-job.yaml
  parameters:
    repository: Repo11
    branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}
    jobname: test2
    project: functionapp/function.csproj'
```

**group-build.yaml**

```
parameters:
  - name: branchRef
    type: string

stages:
 - stage: 'Build'
   displayName: 'Build'         
   jobs: 
   - template: functionapp-build-job.yaml
     parameters:
      branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}

   - template: webapp-build-job.yaml
     parameters:
      branchRef: ${{ parameters.branchRef}}
```

**Pipeline.yaml**

```
variables: 
  - group: test

stages:    
- template: group-build.yaml
  parameters:
    branchRef: ${{ variables.branchRef}}
```

Comment: My issue is similar in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69308466/cant-checkout-the-same-repo-multiple-times-in-a-pipeline

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, that was considered before but I totally missed to add it in the code I provided above. In my build job, I have something like this `- job: JOB_${{ upper(replace(parameters.componentName, '-', '_')) }}_BUILD`. I've been using this template in multiple components ever since and I didn't encounter any issue until I had a requirement to checkout same repo in two build jobs.